# search box, button and gridview

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

How would I implement this:

A user can enter any text in `Textbox1`, then click `Submitbtn1` and then show results in a `Gridview1`. `Clearbtn1` is used to clear all text in the Textbox1.

This would be all done in Visual Studio ASP.NET Web application.

This is what I have done so far:

```
namespace SearchApplication
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void EmptyTextBoxValues(Control parent)
        {
            foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
            {
                if ((c.Controls.Count > 0))
                {
                     EmptyTextBoxValues(c);
                }
                else
                {
                     if (c.GetType().ToString().Equals("System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox"))
                     {
                          ((TextBox)(c)).Text = "";
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         //do nothing
                     }
                 }
             }
         }

         protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             EmptyTextBoxValues(this.Page);
         }

         protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {

         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One tip. Do not do :

```
if (c.GetType().ToString().Equals("System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox"))
                     {
                          ((TextBox)(c)).Text = "";
                     }  .
```

Do

```
TextBox tx = c as TextBox. if(c != null) c.Text = "";
```

As for other things.
When Submit Button is clicked you would get some data / create some data and bind it to the grid using

```
grid.DataSource = myData;
grid.DataBind();
```

Regarding clearing the textbox. If you used normal Asp.net TextBox that you put outside of the Grid, like

```
<asp:TextBox id="Textbox1" runat="server"/>
```

You do not need EmptyTextBoxValues. You can just do Textbox1.Text = ""

Comment: Thanks for the clear...but am having trouble typing a search and returning the search results in the gridview still

Comment: figured it out thanks, i have to use the table adapter feature etc.